# AsyncTask in separate object

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I want to do background tasks in Android to send a request to an API, but I can't get it to work the way I want.

These are my scripts:

Activity class

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

    private ApiRequest ar;
    private String parameters;

    ...

    private void callApi() {
        this.ApiRequest = new ApiRequest(this.parameters);
    }
}
```

ApiRequest class

```
public class ApiRequest {

    private String response;

    public ApiRequest(parameters) {
        new BackgroundTask().execute(parameters);
    }

    protected class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Do stuff here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            this.response = response;
        }

    }
```

Somehow, I can't seem to update the response string from the onPostExecute method. I know onPostExecute is supposed to update the UI thread, but I want to update the object first, which essentially runs in the UI thread (I think). How is this done? I can't find anything about it really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            this.response = response;
        }
```

In this scope, `this` refers to the instance of BackgroundTask and NOT to ApiRequest. I'm surprised your code even compiles.

Change it to `ApiRequest.this.response = response`.

Comment: Seriously, that was all? Okay, I feel silly now. But it did work. I tried it before, at least I started typing it, but since Eclipse couldn't find the variables of the ApiRequest class I thought it wasn't the correct way to do it. Thanks a lot! :)
Edit: oh, and it didn't compile ;)

Comment: Because you have lots of other errors in your code which hid this error ...public ApiRequest(parameters) ... protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Do stuff here
        }
... all invalid. If you had filled them out correctly you would have seen your error.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mention it. This is example code I wrote to paint the picture. This isn't my actual code. The rest of my actual code runs :)

Comment: You should try to have multiple names for your variables within the same code file. Like on onPostExecute calling it resp and then having a global variable called response so when you have to attribute on to another you just have to do it like this: response = resp;

Comment: I'm glad this solved your problem. Please accept the answer :)